# Pass abstract data type with navigate

Tags: angular, typescript

I need pass a abstract data (In Angular 4 or 5) from a component to other component without showing in the url. I see this way:

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: {
      "firstname": "Nic",
      "lastname": "Raboy"
    }
};

this.router.navigate(['home-aluno/'+change.matricula], navigationExtras);
```

But this don't answer my questions. Because Nic and Rabo is in my url

Url example:

http://localhost:4200/home-aluno/001?firstname=Nic&lastname=Raboy

I need something to pass the data and recive in the other component (by navigate) but the data can't stay in my url. Have a way to do this with routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to "pass" information on a route without it appearing in the Url is to use a service.

You can build a very simple service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```

Your first component can set the value into the service and the second component can read the value from the service. This is a very common technique for data sharing.